# android minimum and target SDK

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.3

I have a very basic question.

I have a project which has `minSDKVersion` set to `8` and `targetSDK` version as `16`. Now one of the methods I used `setActionView()` using this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView%28android.view.View%29).

requires a min API level of `11`. 
I just want to know if it'll work in version `2.2` or not??
Or if there is a way to support previous devices?I want to use collapsible action item which requires the use of 'setActionView()'. Is there any other way to use this?

Comment: NO, if it wants API 11 then its not work on 2.2.sorry

Comment: creating an action bar in API < 11 requires an external library, the most popular is [actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Comment: ya I'm using ActionBarSherlock only but I want a collapsible action item which requires the use of setActionView() . Is there any alternative way to use such functionality which would be supported by version 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

If it says this feature requires a minimum API level that is greater than what you set in your manifest, you will have trouble using this feature in these older devices. But check *Android support library*. This may help you support these devices.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using MenuItem *com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem.**setActionView**(View view)* then the support for the same should be there in library and will work on 2.2 .

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out ActionBarCompat, to give you this functionality... (see [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html))

Answer (score 0):

When using android appcompact actionbar library, you could use setActionView with SupportMenuItem.So your code should be like

```
private SupportMenuItem menuItem=(SupportMenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh);
menuItem.setActionView(R.layout.progressbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with the support library:
`MenuItemCompat.setActionView(yourMenuItem, R.layout.your_view);`